# Convert PCM-Data/PCM-File into Wav-Audiofile in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, audio, wav, pcm

I tried to convert a PCM-File with 22050 randomNumbers from -1 to 1 with this method:

```
private void rawToWave(final File rawFile, final File waveFile) throws IOException {

    byte[] rawData = new byte[(int) rawFile.length()];
    DataInputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(rawFile));
        input.read(rawData);
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            input.close();
        }
    }

    DataOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        int myBitsPerSample= 16;
        int myFormat = 1;
        long myChannels = 1;
        long mySampleRate = 22050;
        long myByteRate = mySampleRate * myChannels * myBitsPerSample/8;
        int myBlockAlign = (int) (myChannels * myBitsPerSample/8);

        output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(waveFile));
        // WAVE header
        // see http://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/
        writeString(output, "RIFF"); // chunk id
        writeInt(output, 36 + rawData.length); // chunk size
        writeString(output, "WAVE"); // format
        writeString(output, "fmt "); // subchunk 1 id
        writeInt(output, 16); // subchunk 1 size
        writeShort(output, (short) 1); // audio format (1 = PCM)
        writeShort(output, (short) 1); // number of channels
        writeInt(output, (int)mySampleRate ); // sample ratemySampleRate
        writeInt(output, (int) (myByteRate)); // byte rate
        writeShort(output, (short) myBlockAlign); // block align
        writeShort(output, (short) 16); // bits per sample
        writeString(output, "data"); // subchunk 2 id
        writeInt(output, rawData.length); // subchunk 2 size
        // Audio data (conversion big endian -> little endian)
        short[] shorts = new short[rawData.length /2];
        ByteBuffer.wrap(rawData).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts);
        ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(shorts.length * 2);



        for (short s : shorts) {
           bytes.putShort(s);
        }



        output.write(bytes.array());
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            output.close();
        }
    }
}

public  void writeShortLE(DataOutputStream out, short value) throws IOException {
    out.writeByte(value & 0xFF);
    out.writeByte((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
}



private void writeInt(final DataOutputStream output, final int value) throws IOException {
    output.write(value >> 0);
    output.write(value >> 8);
    output.write(value >> 16);
    output.write(value >> 24);
}

private void writeShort(final DataOutputStream output, final short value) throws IOException {
    output.write(value >> 0);
    output.write(value >> 8);
}

private void writeString(final DataOutputStream output, final String value) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        output.write(value.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

I have a double array with the value 0 from the first element to a specific cutoff and then random numbers until a second point, from this to the end of the file there is 0 again. I made an inverse fft on this array and put the values into a PCM-file. The PCM-File should output a whitenoise, but there is noise over the whole spectrum not only above the cutoff-frequency. It works in Matlab with audiowrite, but not in Java/Android.

Is there a possible problem with the byte-array read from the pcm-file?
I tried to import both wav-files into matlab again (the one converted in android and the one from matlab). The one from matlab has the same amount of values and the same values as the pcm-file. The one converted in android has over 229000 values and random values which are not the same as in the pcm-file. Whats the difference between both conversion methods and why is it working correctly in matlab and not with this method in android?

Comment: `int myBitsPerSample= 2;`

Should this variable have value 16?

Comment: Oh thanks, I will try 2 instead of 16. Doesn't work either with 2 or 16.